Pnpm run build run locally but not with docker build
I am trying to setup a simple dockerfile with pnpm following the pnpm doc for my Nest.js app. I have litteraly copy and past their first dockerfile example
FROM node:20-slim AS base
ENV PNPM_HOME="/pnpm"
ENV PATH="$PNPM_HOME:$PATH"
RUN corepack enable
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

FROM base AS prod-deps
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pnpm,target=/pnpm/store pnpm install --prod --frozen-lockfile

FROM base AS build
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pnpm,target=/pnpm/store pnpm install --frozen-lockfile
RUN pnpm run build

FROM base
COPY --from=prod-deps /app/node_modules /app/node_modules
COPY --from=build /app/dist /app/dist
EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "pnpm", "start" ]

The issue is that when it reaches the step pnpm run build I have this error:
     > [build 2/2] RUN pnpm run build:
1.376 
1.376 > @juniob/backend@1.0.0 prebuild /app
1.376 > rimraf dist
1.376 
1.438 node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1228
1.438   throw err;
1.438   ^
1.438 
1.438 Error: Cannot find module '/app/node_modules/rimraf/dist/esm/bin.mjs'
1.438     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1225:15)
1.438     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051:27)
1.438     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
1.438     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
1.438   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
1.438   requireStack: []
1.438 }
1.438
1.438 Node.js v20.17.0
1.447  ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
------
Dockerfile:13
--------------------
  11 |     FROM base AS build
  12 |     RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pnpm,target=/pnpm/store pnpm install --frozen-lockfile
  13 | >>> RUN pnpm run build
  14 |
  15 |     FROM base
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pnpm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

When I do it locally there is no problem. I cannot solve this. My rimraf version in package.json is 6.0.1.
Does someone knows what's going on?
